# MVC Dropzone.js postback when saving files

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to upload files using Dropzone.js. My code uses ajax to call my Controller but after saving files it does a postback. How can I do this with out the post back?

My Code:

HTML

```
<form action="/Promotion/UploadImages" class="dropzone" id="dzCampaingImages" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @*<form class="dropzone" id="dzCampaingImages" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">*@
        <div class="fallback">
            <input id="inputCampaingImages" name="file" type="file" multiple />
        </div>
    </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
Dropzone.options.dzCampaingImages = {

            //prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            init: function () {
                var submitButton = document.querySelector("#btnUploadSubmit");
                var myDropzone = this; //closure

                submitButton.addEventListener("click", function (files) {

                    //tell Dropzone to process all queued files
                    //myDropzone.processQueue();

                    //return false;
                    //var data = new FormData();
                    //for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    //    data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                    //};

                    var data = new FormData();
                    for (var i = 0; i < myDropzone.files.length; i++) {
                        data.append(myDropzone.files[i].name, myDropzone.files[i]);
                    };

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Content("~/Promotion/UploadImages")',
                        type: "POST",
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        data: data,
                        success: function (response) {
                            //code after success
                            return false;
                        },
                        error: function (er) {
                            alert(er);
                        }

                    });
                });
```

C#

```
public void UploadImages()
    {
        bool isUpload = true;

        HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;

        try
        {
            //foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
            //{
            //    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];

            //    //You can Save the file content here
            //    //
            //    string servPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathTemp_CampaingImages"];
            //    string servFilePath = Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(servPath + file.FileName);

            //    // 
            //    //using (FileStream outStream = new FileStream(servFilePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
            //    //{
            //    //    // 
            //    //    //file.InputStream.CopyTo(outStream);

            //    //}

            //    // 
            //    file.SaveAs(servFilePath);
            //}

            string servPath = context.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathTemp_CampaingImages"]);
            //string servFilePath = Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(servPath + file.FileName);

            string filePath = servPath;

            //write your handler implementation here.
            if (context.Request.Files.Count <= 0)
            {
                context.Response.Write("No file uploaded");
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; ++i)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[i];
                    if (context.Request.Form != null)
                    {
                        string imageid = context.Request.Form.ToString();
                        imageid = imageid.Substring(imageid.IndexOf('=') + 1);

                        if (file != null)
                        {
                            string ext = file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.IndexOf('.'));
                            if (ext.ToLower().Contains("gif") || ext.ToLower().Contains("jpg") || ext.ToLower().Contains("jpeg") || ext.ToLower().Contains("png"))
                            {

                                byte[] data;
                                using (Stream inputStream = file.InputStream)
                                {
                                    MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
                                    if (memoryStream == null)
                                    {
                                        memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                                        inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                                    }
                                    data = memoryStream.ToArray();
                                    //System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath + file.FileName + ".jpg", (byte[])data);
                                    //club.club_image = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }

                    //file.SaveAs(context.Server.MapPath(filePath + file.FileName));
                    //context.Response.Write("File uploaded");
                }
            }
        }
```

I am trying to upload files using Dropzone.js. My code uses ajax to call my Controller but after saving files it does a postback. How can I do this with out the post back?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's because by default a "submit" button also submits the form using a traditional full-page submit, regardless of any JavaScript which also runs when it's clicked.

You can either

1) turn your submit button into a `<button type="button"` instead (which does not do a postback by default)

or

2) use the "preventDefault" function in JavaScript against the event object which is passed to the callback function of your listener:

```
submitButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //...etc
```

This stops the default behaviour of the clicked element (in this case, a form submission) from occurring.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault for more details of this function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Visual Studio was injecting a javascript into my code because of the Browser Link feature. I notice this because of an error that was appering in the browser developer's console.

Here is the link that help me,

[XML Parsing Error](https://forums.asp.net/t/2136615.aspx?XML+Parsing+Error+no+root+element+found)

Another helpful link,
[Using Browser Link VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link)